# Why doesn't ulimit -n work when called inside a script?

Tags: shell-script, debian, file-descriptors

This is very odd. I'm trying to set the `ulimit` to `60000` via my `startup.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

ulimit -n 60000
echo "Hello! File Descriptor set"
```

I can execute this with `./startup.sh` (755 file permissions) and the echo line is printed, and no errors are shown. However, when I do `ulimit -n` it still shows `1024`, what's going on?

What I also find fascinating is I can type `ulimit -n 60000` in the terminal, and then do `ulimit -n` and it works perfectly.  Why can't I set the file descriptor limit through a script?

Debian 8, 64-bit. OpenVZ Container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's simply because the limit was set inside the shell script i.e. the shell (`bash` in this case) spawned by executing the script (kernel actually puts the script as an argument to the shell).

So, once the script execution is done, *that* shell is gone (and the limit) too. And you're back to your original shell.

To test, run the `ulimit -n` inside the script.

Comment: I see. Kept thinking it was a global setting or something, thank you for clearing that up!

Comment: @JohnMiller If you are not willing to craft something up, and happy with user/group based limits, see `/etc/security/limits.conf ` (used by `pam_limits`).

Comment: Oh sweet. Will definitely use that instead. (cant upvote, but pretend I did :))

Answer (score 0):

Processes can only set limits for themselves and their children; what you're trying to set with `ulimit -n` is a global limit, not a per-process one. In order to set global limits as you desire, you could create a Python script using `setrlimit()` and `resource.RLIMIT_NOFILE` from the [`resource`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/resource.html) module.